# Docker: How to redirect a IP within a container to another IP

Tags: docker, iptables

I never touched the iptables for Docker but now I think I have to.
Within a special container, a program/script calls an IP `57.55.10.210`
and I cannot change it (another story). I want to redirect the call
to this IP to `192.168.38.13`. How can do this and does this will have an affect to other containers?
Thanks in advance!
Frank

Comment: this topic already open you can check below. if you need ask any ques please tell clearly.
https://serverfault.com/questions/654441/forward-one-ip-to-a-docker-container Kind Regards Servet TAS

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, but the other post is about how to redirect an IP to a docker container. In my case, I want to redirect the call to an Ip to another IP within a container.

Comment: ok FrankS77 tell me do you want redirect port base ? or all redirect ?

Comment: All redirect. Thank you!

Comment: @ServetTAS: Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to get iptables installed within your container image and assign your container the kernel [capability(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) `NET_ADMIN`.

```
docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN ...
```

See the [docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) and/or the [docker-compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#cap_add-cap_drop)

Then you could add either a entrypoint script, a cmd or a `.rules` file from which you load a rule-set when starting the container. Or you directly embed the rules into the image. In your case the contents of an entrypoint script would look like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 57.55.10.210 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.38.13
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.38.13 -j SNAT --to-source 57.55.10.210
```

Or with the `.rules` file, in your entrypoint script do:

```
/sbin/iptables-restore /some-mounted-volume-or-file
```

In order to get a rules file you could invoke a single run of your container:

```
docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --rm somethingwith/iptables /bin/bash -c "iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 57.55.10.210 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.38.13; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.38.13 -j SNAT --to-source 57.55.10.210; /sbin/iptables-save" > outside-of-container.rules
```

Which will get you something like:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Fri Feb  8 14:42:52 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -d 57.55.10.210/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.38.13
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.38.13/32 -j SNAT --to-source 57.55.10.210
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Feb  8 14:42:52 2019
```

As far as I know this approach should not interfere with other containers on the host.